# XMLHttpRequest response from php function containing no data

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

I am using a codeigniter application that dynamically generates some html elements based on a database query returned from a function in my model.

In one of my views I use XMLHttpRequest to call a php function in one of my controllers which in turn gets data from my model in the form of a string and echos it for the responseText.  My javascript code looks like this:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST", "/controller/my_function", true);
var postStr = "name="+proposalName+"&data="+data;
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.send(postStr);
var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
```

The called function looks like this:

```
public function my_function(){
$data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
$data['data'] = $this->input->post('data');
$string = $this->my_model->my_model_function($data);
echo $string;
}
```

The model returns the string correctly, and even after just echoing a random number or string in the function it still didn't get anything from the response text.  No matter what i try to echo in the function there doesn't appear to be anything in the response text.  What am i doing wrong here?  How can I get the responseText to grab the correct value from my php function?

Edit: fixed a copying issue with postStr variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var post Str = "name="+proposalName+"&data="+data;
```

That is a syntax error. The JavaScript falls over when it hits `Str`. The HTTP request is never sent.

Even if it was sent, you are making an asynchronous request (the third argument to `open` is `true`) so it doesn't lock up the entire page until the response is received. You would be reading `xmlHttp.responseText` before it was set by the response.

You need an `onreadystatechange` function.

See the [MDN documentation for XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) which has examples.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of major issues:

1)  Your Javascript is *not* valid.

```
var post Str = "name="+proposalName+"&data="+data;
```

`post Str` has a space.  This code wouldn't run regardless.

2) You really need to read up on how to use the `XMLHttpRequest`

Read this, it should help:
http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry, i had an error in copying the code over, there is no space there in my real code.

Comment: I changed the third .open parameter to be false and it returned what I wanted it to, it turns out my only fault was my own misunderstanding of how the function was being called!  Thanks for the info since I am a php developer still learning javascript.

Comment: It is bad practice to do synchronous XMLHttpRequests, think twice before you use it in practice.

Comment: You really don't want that third `.open` parameter to be false.  While synchronous *works* for a small definition of works -- it **blocks**.  That is to say, it freezes the entire browser until data has returned.